# Rails Heroku deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

## The issue in general:

I am trying to upload a simple Rails application to Heroku, but I keep getting this error:

[image]

My Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The error tells me to run `bundle exec rake -P` against my code, and it runs without any kind of errors or warning messages.

Any help will be greately appreciated!

Comment: Which version of bundler are you using?

Comment: Can you check if you have `Rakefile` in rootpath of your project ?

Comment: @RahulOjha yes, I do have Rakefile in the project.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan my bundler is in version 2.2.1

Comment: @Shannarra See if [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1106) helps.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I don't have problems with building the repository, my only problem is when I try to deploy to Heroku servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your Bundler version is not compatible with Heroku and not properly supported yet.

Delete your **Gemfile.lock** file then do this on your terminal to revert to an older version of Bundler:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler --version '2.1.4'
bundle install
git add .
git commit -m "Downgraded bundler"
```

Then push again to Heroku.

If after doing those steps and it says along the lines of version 2.2 is required, just delete the Gemfile.lock again, and run `bundle install`